# How to convert ndarray to autograd variable in GPU format?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, pytorch, autograd

I am trying to do something like this,

`data = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(nd_array))`

It comes under the type as `Variable[torch.FloatTensor]`, But I need `Variable[torch.cuda.FloatTensor]` also I want to do this in `pytorch version 0.3.0` which lacks few methods like `to(device)` or `set_default_device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cuda()` method of your tensor.

If you'd like to use specific device you could go with context manager, e.g.

```
with torch.cuda.device(device_index):
    t = torch.FloatTensor(1.).cuda()
```

For more specific information [check documentation for version 0.3.0](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/notes/cuda.html).